# Unable to install sql server 2008 r2 in windows xp sp3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

After Installing Support Files, a pop up occurs stating that Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 installation has encountered an error.

Error Signature:
EventType : sql100msi     P1 : 10.50.1600.1     P2 : 10.50.1600.1
P3 : sqlncli.msi     P4 : 0x2d2816fe     P5 : 0x1603     P6 : install_sqlncli
can anyone help me to resolve

Comment: a quick google search found this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/563608/sql-2008r2x64-setup-failed-on-win2008r2x64#

Can you try workarounds provided? Installing .NET Framework and rebooting.

Comment: i have tried so many solution but its same problem,.